# Detect physical keyboard presence with JavaScript (and differentiate Meta keys)

Tags: javascript, keyboard, detection, navigator

I'm building an app with a CMD-K-triggered combobox. Like many websites, I want to show a prompt instructing users that they can press CMD- (or CTRL-) K to search, but I only want to show that notice to users who have a keyboard attached.

I've dug into the [Keyboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Keyboard_API) to try to find answers, but I'm feeling a bit lost.

I tried a simple `if(!!navigator.keyboard) { ... }` but the prompt still shows on mobile, so I guess all browsers provide a keyboard API even if a physical keyboard isn't attached to the device.

I've also tried to use the keyboard layoutMap's `has()` call for 'Meta,' 'MetaLeft,' and 'MetaRight' (I've learned that's what the CMD key is called on Mac; I know it's the Windows key otherwise so not a complete solution), but it looks like `has()` is limited to only Writing System Keys and you can't detect Functional Keys the same way. Bummer, because this seemed like a great way to only identify physical keyboards and ignore mobile ones.

Turning away from keyboard detection, I reverted to other means of guessing a user's peripherals:

`navigator.userAgentData` isn't supported by Firefox or Safari, so I can't use that yet to get OS info. It looks handy, with a `mobile` boolean and simple `platform` string. Maybe in the future

I'd really rather not show/hide this prompt just based on a responsive breakpoint, but that's been a tempting hack.

`navigator.platform` is deprecated, and my Android test device matches for "Linux" so it shows the prompt when it shouldn't anyway.

---

The closest I've come, and I hate this solution, is to hide the prompt by default and employ the following:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.includes('Macintosh')) {
  // Show prompt, using "CMD"
} else if (
  navigator.userAgent.includes('CrOS')
  || (
    navigator.userAgent.includes('Windows')
    && !navigator.userAgent.includes('Phone')
    && !navigator.userAgent.includes('Xbox')
  )
  || (
    navigator.userAgent.includes('Linux')
    && !navigator.userAgent.includes('Android')
    && !navigator.userAgent.includes('Kindle')
  )
) {
  // Show prompt, using "CTRL"
}
```

This feels bad because I'm still not detecting whether or not someone actually has a keyboard. And because it's a mess. But it hides the prompt on my Android phone and shows it on my Mac! Progress!

Am I going about this all wrong? What am I missing here? This seems like a problem that's been solved many times over and yet I have been unable to find simple (and modern) instructions to implement it myself. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan except since 2012 when that was posted `navigator.platform` has been deprecated... I'm hopeful there's an even better solution from the past decade!

Comment: The [Keyboard API](https://caniuse.com/?search=Keyboard%20API) and the [Navigator API: keyboard](https://caniuse.com/?search=Navigator%3A%20keyboard) both have limited browser support right now. Simplistically you could `document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {...},  {once : true});` to detect first and only first keyboard press or use the [what-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/what-input) library with the caveat "What Input does not make assumptions about the input environment before the page is interacted with".

Comment: @TeaganAtwater you're correct, apologies